# How do I associate my objects so that a many-to-many relation can be used as one-to-many in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please excuse the confusing phrasing in the title. In my RoR project let's say I have it set up like this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

I then have a categories_products table that connects them. This works fine but my problem is that a `product` will only ever have one `category` at a time and I'd of course like to do `product.category` instead of having to deal with an array. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-to-many representation is demonstrated in the rails guides like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: You're right. I had tried those but not gotten them to fit what I wanted to do when it's obvious that they were what I was looking for. I blame the fever I'm currently programming through. Thanks.